# Session Variable error bach booking

Tags: c#

I set up a session variable on the Booking form.aspx as so:

```
    protected void confirmImageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Session["confirmBooking"] = "confirm";
        Session["beachBach"] = beachBachRadioButtonList.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
```

and I transfer to my other page as so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    {
        if (Session["beachBach"] != null)
        {

           numberOfBeachBookingInteger += 1;
           beachBachLabel.Text = numberOfBeachBookingInteger.ToString();

        }
```

I'm trying to add 1 to the beachBach session variable whenever user press the confirm button....however, when i start to debug it, instead of adding 1, it add 2 to the label.

Can someone please help me out.. thanks

Comment: Http is a state less protocol when the page is posted back the value of the variable `numberOfBeachBookingInteger ` may not be available are you sure wat you are doing is right?

Comment: @Nhoc Bem Are you sure you are clearing your sessions properly ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

{
   if(!IsPostBack)
    {
    if (Session["beachBach"] != null)
    {

        numberOfBeachBookingInteger += 1;
       beachBachLabel.Text = numberOfBeachBookingInteger.ToString();

    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks....

by the way, how do u create static int to a label so that when i debug it, it start with "0" instead of blank

Comment: before answering your question can u please explain ur logic..? wat exactly are u trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    {
        if (Session["beachBach"] != null)
        {

           numberOfBeachBookingInteger += 1;
           beachBachLabel.Text = numberOfBeachBookingInteger.ToString();

        }
```

Well what happens after we come to this page ?? Do we have any event that causes `postback` in this page?? 
If there is than definitely it will add `1` again to your `session` .
Try using  `!IsPostBack` property .

Comment: i put the code under the cancel the button so that when the user press the cancel button, session.clear will be executed....

Comment: @NhócBem Well it's good but just one scenario (However it's just a curiosity i don't know the full logic) What will happen if a user comes to this final page and he do not cancels nor proceeds and if he opens a new tab and continues to the same page and this time he confirms then what will be the `numberOfBeachBookingInteger` value ?? I mean user did not cleared session in first tab and now in second tab your `session` is not null so there may be a possibility that it will cause incremented value of `numberOfBeachBookingInteger` again .Please tell me if i am in right direction .